# Add Value On Duplicate Key Update

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, sql-insert, upsert

I have a table with the schema:

```sql
storeId varchar(255),
ttl int,
date varchar(255),
bytes bigint(255),
UNIQUE KEY storeId_date_index (storeId, date)
```

I am wanting to insert a row if it doesn't exist, otherwise update it.

For each duplicate key I hit, I want to sum the old value with the new value. How is this possible with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` command?

Here is what I have so far:

```sql
insert into table (storeId, date, ttl, bytes) 
values 
('477866', '2019-02-05', 54543543, 100),
('6301', '2019-02-05', 54543543, 999999),
('12345', '2019-02-05', 54543543, 999999)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
bytes = oldval + newval # sum old value with new value where storeId and date match in the values
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

> In assignment value expressions in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, you can use the `VALUES(col_name)` function to refer to column values from the `INSERT` portion of the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement.

I.e.:

```
INSERT INTO mhytable(storeId, date, ttl, bytes) 
VALUES 
('477866', '2019-02-05', 54543543, 100),
('6301', '2019-02-05', 54543543, 999999),
('12345', '2019-02-05', 54543543, 999999)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
bytes = bytes + VALUES(bytes)
```